# Fetching visible text from a dropdown in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am trying to fetch visible text from a dropdown which does not have a selected option.
For dropdown which has selected option, i am using below code to fetch value from dropdown.

```
DenominationDropdown = element(by.css('[id*="MainContent_uxDenomination"] select'));
expect(DenominationDropdown.element(by.css('[selected="selected"]')).getText()).toBe('All Denominations');
```

In my second dropdown, there is selected value is not getting populated. I want to fetch current visible value (default value) which in my case is "All Dates" but below code is not working as there is no selected value.

```
DatesDropdown = element(by.css('[id*="MainContent_uxDates"] select'));
expect(DatesDropdown.element(by.css('[selected="selected"]')).getText().toBe('All Dates');;
```

Can someone please suggest a way in protractor to read current visible text or default value of dropdown?

HTML of dropdown:

```
<select name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$body$body$MainContent$MainContent$uxDates" id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_body_body_MainContent_MainContent_uxDates" class="ClassName">
    <option value="%">All Dates</option>
    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
     .......
</select>
```

Comment: What is returned from the failing assertion?  Just an empty string?

Comment: There is no selected option for Dates dropdown so it is throwing error stating element not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it doesn't actually have the attribute `selected=selected` in the HTML, there should be another way.  I tried this in my app on a dropdown and it worked fine:

```
var el = element(by.model('myDropdown')).$('option:checked');
expect(el.getText()).toEqual('test');
```

Note the above was for a dropdown, I originally thought it would be `option:selected` but that threw an invalid locator error.  I have done this for radios in the past too:

```
var el = $('input[type=radio]:checked');
```

And, in case you werent aware, the `$` is syntax equivalent to `element(by.css())`

Comment: This is what i used    `expect(DatesDropdown.element(by.css('option:checked')).getText()).toEqual('All Dates')`

Answer (score 1):

`getText()` should return you the *visible text only*, [by definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#get-element-text), which means that, if you call it on your `select` element, you should get the currently "selected" option:

```
expect(DatesDropdown.getText()).toEqual('All Dates');
```

Comment: This is not working for me. It is giving me all values from dropdown and getting error that expected 'All values from downdown' to equal 'All Dates' `expect(DatesDropdown.getText()).toEqual('All Dates');`

Comment: @NewWorld could you post the HTML representation of this dropdown? Thanks.

Comment: Added HTML of dropdown. Answer from Gunderson worked for me I am still interested to know your insights.

Comment: @NewWorld interesting, the theoretical assumption I made did not work in this case. I had some more ideas about filtering the options using the `element.all()` and `filter()`, but the `:checked` CSS selector seems to me a much better approach. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In the case that doesn´t work with $.('option:checked'). you can try with add to end **element(by.css('option:checked'))**;

```js
var el = element(by.model('myDropdown')).element(by.css('option:checked'));
expect(el.getText()).toEqual('test');
```